# excel vba to execute R script

Tags: excel, vba

I have built an UI in excel to execute the R script. I am using the code below. However, I am getting an error at the last line. Error message is:

> Method 'Run' of object 'IWshShell3'  failed.

Could you please help?

```
Sub RunRscript()

    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 1
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    Dim path As String
    path = "Rscript C:\Desktop\excel2csv.R"
    errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing your path to: path = "Rscript ""C:\Desktop\excel2csv.R"""

Comment: Or check to make sure that is definitely where you file is stored (for most Windows users your desktop is stored in C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop)

Comment: do you have the correct references checked?